# Is there a closed form for the roots of polynomials of degree $n\geq 7$ with zero linear coefficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I know there is no closed form for the roots of a generalized degree $n\geq 5$ polynomial, but is there a closed form or anything non-obvious/interesting we can say about the roots of a polynomial of the form 
$$p(x)= \sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$$
with $a_1=0$, and $n\geq 7$?

EDIT: Then, is the following true

For $n\geq 5$, the roots of the polynomial above $p(x)$ have a closed form if we let at least $n-4$ coefficients $a_k$ be zero?

EDIT: Oh no, I meant the sum above to go from k=0. Sorry.

Comment: There is certainly not a general closed form for all of the roots of the polynomials you describe, since they includes the case of $a_0=0$, after taking out the two zero roots you get a polynomial of degree $\geq 5$, and we know there is no closed form for the roots of that

Comment: Galois theory is interesting. It tells you how to see when a formula still exists for higher order polynomial equations. This is a course of study, not something I can put in an answer...

Comment: If $a_1=0$ we have that $$\sum_{k=1}^na_kx^k=\sum_{k=2}^na_kx^k=x^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}a_kx^k$$ but the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}a_kx^k$ is of degree at least $5$.

Comment: If $a_1=0$, then you can say the sum of the roots is 0, i.e. the polynomial is centered about $x=0$.